# Print all functions output of class in php?

Tags: php, class

Hi friends i am new to **php** , and i am trying to learn classes 
i am trying the following code with which i get all **functions** **name** **described** in the class
can anybody tell me **how** can i print the **output** of **functions** in the **class**

```
<?php
    class dog {
                    public function bark() {
                    print "Woof!\n";
                    }

                    public function legs() {
                    print "four!\n";
                    }
             }

    class poodle extends dog {
      public function yip() {
            print "Yipppppppp!\n";
        }
    }

    $poppy = new poodle;

    //$poppy->bark();
    $class_methods = get_class_methods(new poodle());
    //echo    $class_methods;
        foreach($class_methods as $class_methods1)
        {
        echo $class_methods1.'<br/>';
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$poodle = new poodle();
$class_methods = get_class_methods($poodle);
//echo    $class_methods;
foreach($class_methods as $class_method)
{
    echo $class_method.'\'s Output: '.$poodle->$class_method()."<br />"; 
}
```

In general:

If you have a value like `$test = "abc"` you can evaluate it (in php) to either a variablename, or a function etc.:

```
$test = "abc";
$test() // equal to abc() - if function abc exists.

echo $$test // equal to echo $abc - if $abc is defined.

$anotherTest = new $test(); // equal to new abc() - if class exists.
```

Comment: THANKS THATS A PREETY NICE ANSWER WITH THIS I UNDERSTAND BOTH FUNCTION AND ITS OUTPUT

Comment: @RohitGoel Added a general example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$poppy = new poodle;

$class_methods = get_class_methods($poppy);

foreach($class_methods as $class_method_name)
{
    echo $class_methods_name.' => '
        // Either:
        .$poppy->$class_method_name()
        // OR (prefered method, but more typing)
        .call_user_func(array($poppy, $class_method_name))

        .'<br/>';

}
```

Comment: thanks for replying  but as a beginner this is little hard for me

Answer (score 0):

A variable can be used in place of the method name to do what you want. Note: you don't need to `echo` the result of the method calls because your methods all `print` something but they don't actually return anything.

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/2JRLtrQV)**

```
$poppy = new poodle;

$class_methods = get_class_methods($poppy);

foreach($class_methods as $class_methods1)
{
   $poppy->$class_methods1() . '<br/>';
}
```

**Outputs**

```
Yipppppppp!
Woof!
four!
```